# Microsoft Exchange 2010 - how to find out the host name?

Tags: dns, exchange-server-2010

I have installed a Microsoft Exchange 2010 on one of my servers and set the DNS records properly but my emails are not getting through (Error message is: The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect). I suspect it has something to do with the way I configured my exchange server host name (i.e., I might have mistyped mail.mydomain.tld to something else when I run the setup) but I did not backed up the configuration. And when I go to mail.mydomain.tld I got:

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

I am just wondering if there is anyway I can still retrieve what was configured initially?